# Dodgy App ripping me off?

Tags: virus

I am suspicious about the following:

- My data usage tripled last month.
- I have found an app which I don't recognize.
- I have received multimedia messages from someone who denies sending any.

Is it possible that I could have been sent some sort of virus in a multimedia message which has installed the app (BestDeals), which then uses my data allowance to rip me off?

I have uninstalled other apps, but it doesn't seem to be possible for apps like this. How might I uninstall it?

Comment: Go to settings>mobile data and see which apps uses the data most

Answer (score 0):

Most shady apps pull you into setting them as a device administrator. Device admin apps have additional access to your device and cannot be removed *unless* you remove them from the Device Admin list.

**To manage device administrators**:
Go to Settings > Security > Device admin apps (or a similar entry) and remove admin access from all the apps. *Or at least from apps which you do not recognize.*

Once an app is off device admin list, it can be removed off just like any other app.

You can also check for the amount of data consumed by an app by checking the data usage stats. That'll help you better understand the culprit app.